# Two DNS providers for one Domain Name?

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers

I have a domain name `www.example.com` hosted by Namecheap.

Namecheap just got hit with a huge DDOS which meant the domain name stopped responding and in turn one of my customers websites wasn't accessible via the domain name (IP only).

Is it possible to have a backup service whilst still having the domain externally hosted so if it's not responding via namecheap, it can lookup the address from another source?

The TTL value on the domain name is very low, could this also have an impact? If I increase the time, would it help?

I don't normally worry about this area but this DDOS has got me thinking so apologies if my terminology is wrong on a few points ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can, in fact it's very much advised to have 2 DNS servers running on separate networks. At Namecheap there should be an option to set DNS servers for your domains. It might be hidden as an "advanced" option. Basically all you'll need to do is find another DNS provider, setup your DNS there the same as it is at Namecheap, and set the secondary DNS server on Namecheap to your new DNS provider. This way if Namecheap's DNS server goes down for any reason all queries will go to the secondary provider. If you're very worried about this problem, you can even set third and fourth DNS servers.

Comment: Oh, I see now. This is the purpose of the nameservers. Right, got it :) Thanks.

Comment: Checkout http://intodns.com/yourdomainhere.com for common DNS configuration problems and best practices. It's a helpful tool for learning DNS.